# Is there any way to add more values in picklist, without using MetaData API?

Tags: apex, picklist

I want to add values in picklist, other then default values which are given at the time of creation of custom object field with data type Picklist.
Suppose I created a custom object named: customObject__c then i created a new custom field with data type picklist and provided values while creation. 
Now I want to add more values in that but from the Apex code.
Is there any way to add more values in picklist, without using MetaData API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in Apex using [this](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) awesome wrapper class, but it still utilizes the Metadata API. There is a great example of updating a picklist value [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls)

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to use the metadata api.